# Excel BubbleChart MarkerShape won't Change

Tags: vba, excel, bubble-chart

The following script checks for each point of a bubblechart if the value of the cell in column "B" is `A` or `P`.

Then it should change the shape of the respective Marker to either a circle (same as before, for value `A`) or a diamond (for value `P`).
It partly works, because I get the right output in the direct window, but the shape of the marker still stays the same, why?

[The Markerstyle property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/series-markerstyle-property-excel)

Code:

```
Sub format_chart()
Dim srs As Series
Dim cht As Chart

Set cht = Sheets("Diagramme").ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Chart
For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
    If Range("B" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(srs.Name, Sheets("Diagrammdaten").Range("a:a"), 0)).Value = "A" Then
         srs.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleDiamond
         Debug.Print "Value is A"
    ElseIf Range("B" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(srs.Name, Sheets("Diagrammdaten").Range("a:a"), 0)).Value = "P" Then
         srs.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
         Debug.Print "Value is P"
    Else: Debug.Print "You Failed!"
    End If
Next srs

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean bubble chart? You cannot change shape of marker in bubble chart, as far as I know. You can do it with scatter plot however. If you meant scatter plot, set that in line:

```
srs.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleDiamond
```

You set market style for the whole serie. If you want change style for single point, you should loop through srs.Points collection.

Comment: is it possible to set the size of the points of a scatter plot in vba, so it displays data similiar to the bubble chart?

Comment: This is possible in spreadsheet, so it is is probably possible in VBA as well. Just record macro and watch the code.

Comment: Solved the issue by not changing the markers but use different borderstyles. Thank you for your help!